# Duda sobre abrir el primer archivo de una carpeta

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

espero alguien que tenga mas experiencia que yo me pueda ayudar, desconozco si esto sea posible o si exíste alguna función.

Mi problema es que tengo una imagen a la cual le doy click y esta me manda al archivo que deseo.

El problema es que tengo que especificar el nombre exacto del archivo.

Ya que este archivo va a estar cambiando de información y de nombre y tengo que actualizar la href cada vez que esto suceda.

Hay alguna manera de hacerlo automático.

Que escoja el primer archivo que encuentre en la carpeta o el único archivo que este en la carpeta, hay alguna forma de hacer esto??.

```
<a href="Documentos/Archivo1.pdf" target="_blank"> <img src="Imagenes/alerta.png" class="slider__img" id="img-4"></a>
```

Actualizacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
$MiDir = '/var/www/misitio/Documentos/';
if ($handle = opendir($MiDir)) {
  while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    if (!is_dir($file)) {
      $MiArchivo = $file;
      break;
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
if (isset($MiArchivo)) {
  echo '<a href="Documentos/'.$MiArchivo.'" target=_"blank">clic aquí</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: tienes un problema de arquitectura o diseño... puedes explicar donde y para que muestras el archivo??? y que codigo aparte de un link html tienes???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código encontrará el primer archivo del directorio y luego, si encontró alguno, *imprimirá* un *link* hacia dicho archivo.

```php
$MiDir = '/var/www/misitio/Documentos/';
if ($handle = opendir($MiDir)) {
  while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    if (!is_dir($file)) {
      $MiArchivo = $file;
      break;
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
if (isset($MiArchivo)) {
  echo '<a href="Documentos/'.$MiArchivo.'" target=_"blank">clic aquí</a>';
}
```

Documentación de las funciones:

- [opendir()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.opendir.php)
- [readdir()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readdir.php)
- [closedir()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.closedir.php)
- [is_dir()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir.php)
- [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset)

Comment: Hola gracias por tu ayuda al poner el codigo me sale esto : clic aquí'; } ?> No se cual sea el problema le estoy tratando de resolver pero no encuentro el problema.

Comment: ¿Te sale qué? ¿en dónde?

Comment: Puse la imagen en la pregunta, al parecer no marca completo el tag y no se puede seleccionar es como si alguna de las comillas estuviera mal o faltara alguna.

Comment: Creo que algo estás trasladando mal... si ves, mi código no tiene ningún `?>` que es con lo que usualmente cierras un segmento _php_. Eso no debiera aparecer en la salida... así que probablemente te falte cerrar alguna cadena (lo digo de puro _feeling_).

Comment: Estas sentencias que utilizaste son de php asi que puse mi codigo en php lo unico que agregue fue el segmento de php y aunque le quite <?php y ?> no me toma el codigo o tu codigo donde lo deberia de agregar?

Comment: mi código termina con un cierre de etiqueta `</a>`, el tuyo, aparentemente, después de `aquí` y tiene un punto y coma y el cierre de php. Pero no se trata de copiar y pegar, sino de entender el funcionamiento... yo escribí el código en el propio navegador; es probable que se me colara algún detalle... aunque lo he leído ya 5 o 6 veces y no lo veo mal. Considero que si entiendes su funcionamiento, estarás en condiciones de adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125011/discussion-between-jachguate-and-victor-a).